# WPF: How to trigger target controls to update when changing binding object members

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I've been searching for hours to figure this out; I am possibly trying to find something that doesn't exist, or my design is off-base.

I have a WPF page with a DependencyProperty that associates with a nested class structure.  eg:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyDepProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MyDep", typeof(MyGrouping), typeof(MainWindow));

public MyGrouping MyDep {
    get => (MyGrouping) GetValue(MyDepProperty);
    set => SetValue(MyDepProperty, value);
}
public class MyObject {
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
}

public class MyGrouping {
    public MyObject G1 { get; set; }
    public MyObject G2 { get; set; }
    public MyObject G3 { get; set; }
}
```

On my page are TextBox controls that bind to paths in this dependency property.  eg:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyDep.G2.A, Mode=TwoWay,
         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="50"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyDep.G2.B, Mode=TwoWay, 
         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="50"/>
```

Also on my page, for each grouping, is a "clear" button, in which I expect to clear the values in the object.   Trying to keep from having to manipulate TextBox objects in the code-behind, I wanted to be able to adjust values directly in the dependency property and have them reflected in the controls auto-magically.  eg:

```
    private void G2Clear_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        MyDep.G2.A = MyDep.G2.B = "";
        // ??  What do I do here?
    }
```

So the question is:  Is there a way I can tell WPF to trigger all controls to update to current values in the dependency property's properties?  I've tried a number of methods and they don't seem to work -- InvalidateProperty(), SetPropertyValue(), etc.  (I was shotgunning to see what works.)

My object does have a copy constructor, so I *can* do this:

```
MyDep = new MyGrouping(MyDep)
```

And it does effectively update the controls -- but I feel like this is a drastic approach; isn't there some middle ground where I can just have the controls re-evaluate the depencency property without having to name and access each and every control on the page?

Comment: `MyObject` and `MyGrouping` (and *any* object along a binding path) should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and then raise a `PropertyChanged` event when any of its properties changes (pass in the name of the changed property to the event args constructor).  If you do this, the binding target will automatically update when the source changes.

Comment: Thank you, Mike... I had been trying to stay blind to how the property-changed aspects worked before now.   Having looked at it I realize that I'd have to make some drastic changes to my classes to support this, and these classes are used elsewhere too.  I didn't take the MVVM approach with this application and my objects are shared across several modules of my application.

Comment: If you're binding to classes that you don't 'own', you can always wrap them in model classes that support change notification.